# Deploy asp.net webpage error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to upload an asp.net webpage to 1and1 servers but I get an error and I don't know how to solve it.
You can see the error here: http://academua.es/

In order to deploy it I clicked the publish option in visual studio and selected file system. Don't know what else to do, it is the first webpage I upload, thanks everyone.

Comment: Could you provide you web.config file? It seems that problem somewhere there...

Comment: if you publish to file system, you save files to your local folder. You need then copy to hosting, for example by ftp.

Comment: Something is wrong with your web.config

Comment: @PavelPykhtin http://textuploader.com/5bj0m That's my web.config

Comment: Provided config is ok. But have you copied it from the server or from local computer? If you have some transforms applied to release configuration they will be applied to a web.config on publish. This could produce duplicated sections in you web.config on the server.

Comment: @PavelPykhtin I tried uploading the web publishing it directly in ftp like they suggested and now I get a different error. The web.config is the one from my project, do I need to use the one from the server?

Comment: Yes, it's better to use you 'production' web.config as it might differ from that you use for development.

Comment: First step would be to disable custom error messages in the web.config as described on the error page. Otherwise you can't see the real error...

Comment: As mentioned above - either turn error show on in the config or you can check the event viewer of the server - but we'll need the actual real error message to be able to help you.